# Conditions on $A$ such that the homogeneous linear system $Ax=0$ has a positive solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Are there conditions on an $n\times m$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$, such that the homogeneous linear system $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ has a positive (non-zero) solution?

Suppose that $n<m$ and that $\operatorname{rank}({\mathbf{A}})=n$.

By positive (non-zero) vector, I mean $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $\mathbf{x}\ge \mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf{x}\ne \mathbf{0}$.

---

*Comments:*

- Ideally, I would be interested in necessary and sufficient conditions but I would also be interested in sufficient conditions.
- Farkas' lemma doesn't seem to apply to this case as far as I can tell.
- [This paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968384) addresses exactly this question but it does not give a condition on $\mathbf{A}$. It, instead, reduces the system to one equivalent equation.

Comment: Do you know the sign pattern of $A$? Also what is the rank of this matrix?

Comment: What is a "positive" vector?

Comment: @aschepler I clarified what I mean by a positive non-zero vector in the question.

Comment: @KBS Is there a condition on the sign pattern that would be helpful? I am basically asking for any condition that would make it work. Based on the results in the paper that I link to, it does seem like the sign pattern should matter.

Comment: There are conditions for sign-matrices. They are given there https://journals.uwyo.edu/index.php/ela/article/download/43/43

Comment: So if I understand it right (and sorry my answer did not) there are $2^n$ "quadrants" determined by sign pattern and an $r-$ dimensional subspace ($n\gt r\gt 0$) will intersect $2^r$ of these. Take $r$ to be the rank, and the chance of a random matrix of rank $r$ intersecting the positive 'quadrant' will likely be $2^{r-n}$.

Comment: @KBS Thank you for the reference, it is indeed quite helpful. I still need some time to understand it, but as far as I can tell they establish sign consistency (which they define as having a solution to the problem above) only for the non-homogeneous case. They investigate sign solvability for the homogeneous case, but that is actually about being able to sign each element of the solution which I not necessary in my case. It is interesting to me that the homogeneous case seems to be more difficult to characterize.

Comment: Have you tried to look at the positive rank of the matrix. I would suspect that this would be the key in your problem. This is the rank of the matrix but under positive linear combinations.

Comment: Ok since I have searched on the topic, I got paper alerts today. They mention this one: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379518302088. Also, check the references therein.

Comment: @KBS Thanks again for your help. It took me some time, but I have now looked into your suggestions and so far haven't really found any condition on a non-square matrix A that implies the existence of a positive solution. If you have figured something out, do you mind writing it up as an answer?

Comment: @mzp It is unlikely there is a general answer. You may find or develop sufficient conditions but they will not be necessary. Another point is that problems are usually structured and this structure can sometimes be exploited as it may make things easier. Without assumptions on $A$ it is difficult to provide sufficient conditions. Necessary conditions are easy to obtain.

Comment: @mzp Actually, you can adapt the results for the square case to the rectangular case. If you can find a square submatrix that satisfies the conditions for a nonnegative solution, then you are pretty much done.